# How to make enotez list page numbers instead of reference numbers?

Tags: memoir, enotez

My MWE below correctly lists references numbers next to the text and in the endnotes listing.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% \setenotez{backref=true}
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\endnote{Endnote A}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote B}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote C}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote D}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote E}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote F}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the book I'm writing is popular nonfiction, where the convention is to hide the reference numbers next to the text and to list the page numbers alongside the endnotes, like this:

[image]

Is the above possible with enotez?

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? Because exactly the same question just came up for me.

Comment: @JoelDerfner no, I never figured it out. But I decided that I wanted to have the reference numbers after all. I talked to a number of people and did an informal survey on a reddit writing group and everyone had agreed that it's kind of nutty to have references without reference numbers in the text. Personally, I never liked hiding the reference numbers and was just going along with popular non-fiction convention. But now I'm glad that I added the reference numbers. Sorry it's not the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way `enotez` processes the endnote number with the `\enotez_write_list_number:n` command when it prints the list, I could not figure how to change the behavior using the built-in templates. Instead, I just defined a new template where the code

```
\enotez_list_number:n
  { \enotez_write_list_number:n {##1} }
```

is replaced with

```
\enotez_list_number:n
  { \pageref{custom:enotez:##1} }
```

and we add a label `custom:enotez:\@currentlabel` to every enotezmark. To remove the endnote mark, we just need

```
\renewcommand{\enotezwritemark}[1]{}
```

Here's your example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\enotezwritemark}[1]{}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{cmd/enotez_endnote_mark:n/after}
  {
    \label{custom:enotez:\@currentlabel}
  }
\DeclareTemplateInterface {enotez-list} {customlist} {1}
  {
    heading       : function 1 = \enotezlistheading {#1} ,
    format        : tokenlist  = \footnotesize           ,
    number        : function 1 = \enmark{#1}             ,
    number-format : tokenlist  = \normalfont             ,
    list-type     : tokenlist  = description
  }
\DeclareTemplateCode {enotez-list} {customlist} {1}
  {
    heading       = \enotez_list_heading:n           ,
    format        = \l__enotez_list_format_tl        ,
    number        = \enotez_list_number:n            ,
    number-format = \l__enotez_list_number_format_tl ,
    list-type     = \l__enotez_list_type_tl
  }
  {
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \enotez_set_totoc:
    \enotez_list_heading:n { \l__enotez_list_name_tl }
    \enotez_list_preamble:
    \enotez_build_print_list:nnnn {#1}
      {
        \group_begin:
          \tl_use:N \l__enotez_list_format_tl
          \begin{\l__enotez_list_type_tl}
      }
      {
        \item
          [
            \enotez_list_number:n
              { \pageref{custom:enotez:##1} } % this is the only changed line
          ]
        % \cs_set:cpn {@currentlabel}
        %   { \p@endnote \l__enotez_endnote_mark_tl }
        \tl_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_text_tl
      }
      {
          \end{\l__enotez_list_type_tl}
        \group_end:
      }
    \enotez_list_postamble:
  }
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{customlist}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext\endnote{Endnote A}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote B}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote C}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote D}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote E}

\blindtext\endnote{Endnote F}

\printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```

[image: enotez]

Comment: Hmm. Using this I get "invalid environment command" errors at \begin{\l__enotez_list_type_tl} and \end{\l__enotez_list_type_tl}.  (They don't prevent compiling—they just don't give the desired result.) Any thoughts on how to deal with this? FWIW I'm using the octavo class, not the memoir class—though if your solution was memoir-specific then I guess I'm SOL.

Comment: @JoelDerfner If I copy the document above and replace "memoir" with "octavo", I get no errors. If this produces errors for you, I suggest you open a new question that includes the test document and log file